# Como fazer stream vídeo com pedido de intervalo?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Eu tenho um vídeo salvo no banco de dados com tipo VARBINARY(MAX).

Como eu posso fazer um range request ?

O código a seguir obtem o vídeo completo do banco de dados e joga na variável `video_byte`; Isso é um problema para o vídeo grande, para evitar isso preciso montar range requests. Segue o código a seguir como eu estou fazendo agora:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetStreamVideo()
{    
    var result = await _context.Files
        .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    byte[] video_byte = result.Video;    
    if (video_byte == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    return File(video_byte, "video/mp4");
}
```

Como eu posso obter pedaço por pedaço em asp.net core ?

O código a seguir funciona muito bem no asp.net mvc normal(sem core), e também uso a biblioteca: https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetStreamVideo()
{
    byte[] test = null;
    DateTime lastModificationDate = DateTime.MinValue;

    using (var ctx = new Entities())
    {
        var result = ctx.Files.Where(x => x.Id == 1).SingleOrDefault();

        test = result.Video;
        lastModificationDate = result.LastModificationDate;
    }

    return new RangeFileContentResult(test, "video/mp4", "Name.mp4", lastModificationDate);
}
```

Comment: [Tenho um exemplo aqui](https://github.com/Wurthma/GerenciadorDocumentoWebAPI/blob/master/GED/Controllers/MediaController.cs) que pode ser útil pra você. Adaptei de outro exemplo que está documentado no meu código. Não vou conseguir responder agora, mas se disser que é útil posso tentar adaptar algo pro seu cenário se tiver diferenças.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann vou olhar o link, obrigado.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann olhei no seu código, na linha onde tem `SingleOrDefault();` não vai obter o vídeo completo ?

Comment: Nessa linha ele não está pegando o arquivo, apenas o registro no BD referente ao vídeo. Nesse registro tem o caminho onde o arquivo está armazenado o arquivo ele lê um pouco mais abaixo em 'fileInfo'  e esse arquivo é retornado em ranges para streaming, é isso que precisa?

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann Isso, mesmo ! A ideia é não obter o vídeo completo e sim pedaço por pedaço. Porque no meu código ele está retornando byte_array completo do banco de dados. O select demora uns 20 segundos. Isso é um problema.

Comment: Entendi Matheus, mas o meu exemplo não contorna esse problema, meu arquivo não fica salvo no BD... no exemplo o BD armazena apenas o caminho físico dele pra depois ele ser carregado, qual é o BD utilizado?

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann MS Sql Server 17

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90783/discussion-between-matheus-miranda-and-george-wurthmann).

Answer (score 2):

Isto pode ser feito, consultando os headers do pedido. Mais especificamente o header `Range`. Daí, você pode usar `ByteRangeStreamContent` para retornar apenas uma porção do video. Em termos de base de dados não pode fazer básicamente nada, uma vez que não é possível saber onde se encontra a porção do video que você está à procura de forma determinística, pelo menos não duma forma simples.

```
var range = Request.Headers.Range?.Ranges?.FirstOrDefault();
if (range != null)
{
    var stream = File.Open(record.FilePath, FileMode.Open,
        FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
    response.Content = new ByteRangeStreamContent(stream, new RangeHeaderValue(range.From, range.To), "audio/mp3");
    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
else
{
    var stream = File.Open(record.FilePath, FileMode.Open,
        FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```